# Matching delimited text, taking into account level

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I am looking for a way to replace

```
\cmd1{stuff \cmd2{other stuff}}
```

with

```
(stuff \cmd2{other stuff})
```

I have tried

```
:%s/\\cmd1{\(.\{-}\)}/(\1)/gc
```

However, this returns

```
(stuff \cmd2{other stuff)}
```

since the first `}` after `{` is taken because of `\{-}` -- taking the greedy version does not help, in the case that there is another `}` later on the line.

Is there a better expression to put inside `{\( \)}` so that `\( \)` encompasses everything up to the matching `}` to `{`?

Comment: I'm presuming you need it to work for arbitrary numbers of nested `cmds`? e.g. `\cmd1{stuff \cmd2{other stuff \cmd3{even more stuff}}}` ?

Comment: And for multiple matches on the line? `\cmd1{stuff \cmd2{other stuff}} more stuff \cmd1{even more stuff \cmd2{yet other stuff}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regular Expression

If you *don't* need to be able to support arbitrary levels of nesting, (if there's never a `\cmd3` inside your `\cmd2`), then you can do this by incorporating the inner brackets into your expression, and matching "any character that's not a bracket" `[^}]` instead of "any character" `.`:

```
:%s/\\cmd1{\([^{]*{[^}]*}\)}/(\1)/gc
```

### Macro Alternative

Otherwise, you can use a macro instead:

You're using the `c` confirm flag to inspect every change, so try the following:

1. `/\\cmd1{<Cr>`: Find the first `\cmd1`
2. `qq`: Start recording
3. `dt{`: delete the `\cmd1`
4. `%`: Jump to matching `}`
5. ``` r)``r( ```: Replace curly brackets with round ones
6. `n`: Jump to next match
7. `q`: Stop recording

Then press `@q` to repeat the change, or `n` to skip this instance and jump to the next. After you've used `@q` at least once, you can use `@@` as a faster shortcut.

If you actually don't want to review the changes as you make them, you can make the macro recursive by changing the recording steps 2–7 to:

```
qqqqqdt{%r)``r(n@qq
```

You can then invoke it a single time to make all the changes in one go: `@q`

Comment: For posterity, there is also a way to do it with a global command, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437206/how-to-substitute-for-matching-delimiters-in-vi .